# Using a for loop for multiple value inputs

Tags: java

I was wondering how I can get an input after every line of my for loop.

```
System.out.println("How many days?");
int days = keyboard.nextInt();

int A = 0;
int B = 0;
int C = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < days; ++i(
{
  System.out.println("Enter an input for day " +i + "of A B C:");
}
```

It prints out

```
Enter an input for day 1 of A B C:
Enter an input for day 2 of A B C:
```

Depending on the value of days which is good. But I need to enter a value for A B C after every day instead of just printing them all at once.  How can i proceed to do this?

Comment: Have you tried moving that code inside your loop?

Comment: Just as a tip you could simplify your variable declarations to: `int A, B, C;`. Their default values will be 0.

Comment: @petehallw: in Java fields of a class (and elements of an array) are default-initialized to zero/false/null depending on type, but local variables are not. Although if these variables are assigned without first being read, as makes sense and done in Jerome's answer, the lack of initialization doesn't matter.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the info, did not know that somehow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guesing you did :

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

somewhere in your code above.

```
System.out.println("How many days?");
    int days = keyboard.nextInt();


int A = 0;
int B = 0;
int C = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < days; ++i)
{
  System.out.println("Enter an input for day " +i + "of A:");
   int A = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

Move your scanner code inside the for loop to take input. Not sure what A,B,C are in the context. But if you need A, B and C for all n days then just repeat the two lines in the for loop for B and C.

Comment: Wow thank you very much i hadn't considered moving the int a = keyboard.nextint into the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use your `Scanner keyboard`

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many days?");
int days = keyboard.nextInt();

int A = 0;
int B = 0;
int C = 0;

for(int i = 1; i < days; ++i(
{
  System.out.println("Enter an input for day " +i + "of A:");
  A = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter an input for day " +i + "of B:");
  B = keyboard.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter an input for day " +i + "of C:");
  C = keyboard.nextInt();
}
```

If you want to input A, B and C in one call you can use `String abcInput = keyboard.nextLine();` and then proceed the `String`:

```
String abcInput = keyboard.nextLine();
String[] split = abcInput.split(" ");
if(split.length == 3){
    //3 Values found so assign it to A,B and C
    A = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);            
    B = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);            
    C = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);            
}else{
    System.out.println("Not enough input");
}
```